# SEO Reseller Programs

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you evaluate SEO/SEM companies? What are common services/prices?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/how-do-you-evaluate-seo-sem-companies-what-are-common-services-prices)

How do I compare SEO reseller programs? Seems like support, pricing, and results would would be the major factors, but I really have no idea.

Comment: @John Conde: "How to pick a hosting company?" vs "How to pick a hosting reseller program?" -- how is a question about selecting a reseller program for SEO the exact same as picking a SEO company?

Comment: Is there that much of a difference when it comes to SEO? Especially with SEO being subjective? Plus this might be off topic as it doesn't have anything to do with a website you control.

Comment: @JohnConde: Are you saying all of the reseller questions on webmasters.SE are off-topic, since by default, and reseller would not owned either the service, nor the company using the service. And yes, after reviewing three so far, there are huge differences, and I'm unable to tell at a high-level even how the companies compare; basically just doing a Google for SEO resellers. Putting aside that though, at this point being off-topic appears to be a much larger issue, than if this question is a exact duplicate.